# Triggering yaml file when a certain label is applied to the pull request

Tags: yaml, github-actions

I am working on a project where I need to create a tweet from an account whenever a certain issue or pull request has a label `issue/tweet`

I am able to make tweet when label is applied to issue but unable to do so when the same lable is applied to a pr

the .yml file I am working on

```
name: Send a Tweet

on:
  issues:
    -label: issue/tweet
  pull_request:
    types: [labeled]

jobs:
  tweet:
    if: ${{github.event.label.name == 'issue/tweet'}}
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: ethomson/send-tweet-action@v1
        with:
          status: ${{github.event.issue.html_url}} "#opensource"
          consumer-key: ${{ secrets.TWITTER_CONSUMER_API_KEY }}
          consumer-secret: ${{ secrets.TWITTER_CONSUMER_API_SECRET }}
          access-token: ${{ secrets.TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN }}
          access-token-secret: ${{ secrets.TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET }}
```

expected to make a tweet when pr is labeled with `issue/tweet'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's dissect the important parts...

### Workflow sections

#### `on` events

You want [`issues`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/events-that-trigger-workflows#issues) and [`pull_request`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/events-that-trigger-workflows#pull_request) to trigger the workflow and I think both of them should have their `types` set to `labeled`.

#### `if` job condition

The condition needs to be applied to the correct object within `github.event`. For each of these events, the content is different. It's defined in [Webhook events and payloads](https://docs.github.com/en/developers/webhooks-and-events/webhooks/webhook-events-and-payloads).

Both [`issue`](https://docs.github.com/developers/webhooks-and-events/webhooks/webhook-events-and-payloads#issues) and [`pull_request`](https://docs.github.com/developers/webhooks-and-events/webhooks/webhook-events-and-payloads#pull_request) should have `github.event.label` so I'm not sure why it wouldn't work. It might be a good idea to [dump the entire context](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/dump-context) at the beginning of your job in order to debug it.

However, both events also have `github.event.TYPE.labels`, an array of label objects. Therefore, it might be a better option to use that and apply [`contains`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/expressions#contains) expression on it:

```
contains(github.event.TYPE.labels.*.name, 'issue/tweet')
```

### Result

```yaml
name: Send a Tweet

on:
  issues:
    types: [labeled]
  pull_request:
    types: [labeled]

jobs:
  tweet:
    if: >-
      (
        contains(github.event.pull_request.labels.*.name, 'issue/tweet') ||
        contains(github.event.issue.labels.*.name, 'issue/tweet')
      )
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: crazy-max/ghaction-dump-context@v1
      - uses: ethomson/send-tweet-action@v1
        with:
          status: ${{github.event.issue.html_url}} "#opensource"
          consumer-key: ${{ secrets.TWITTER_CONSUMER_API_KEY }}
          consumer-secret: ${{ secrets.TWITTER_CONSUMER_API_SECRET }}
          access-token: ${{ secrets.TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN }}
          access-token-secret: ${{ secrets.TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET }}
```